# My App is getting Crash stating index 21 beyond bounds [0 .. 19]' *** First throw call stack:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am doing a chatting app and retriving data from firebase. But after chatting some time it's crashing. I'm not able to find in which array is the problem. Please help me in which array I have to find out. I am using Jsqmessageviewcontroller library.

```
NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 21 beyond bounds [0 .. 19]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x03bbc946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02d33a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x03a92a93 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 243
    3   UIKit                               0x022f0a67 -[_UIFlowLayoutSection frameForItemAtIndexPath:] + 142
    4   UIKit                               0x022b5273 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _frameForItem:inSection:usingData:] + 123
    5   UIKit                               0x022b0e07 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:usingData:] + 510
    6   UIKit                               0x022b1037 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:] + 339
    7   ChatApp                             0x001af154 -[JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:] + 100
    8   ChatApp                             0x001b05ab -[JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] + 123
    9   ChatApp                             0x001c53a2 -[JSQMessagesViewController scrollToBottomAnimated:] + 1266
    10  ChatApp                             0x000a2fe7 __37-[ChatpageViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke_3 + 103
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x045ff30a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0461fe2f _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0460690e _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 606
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x03b1695e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x03ad5760 __CFRunLoopRun + 2256
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x03ad4bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x03ad49fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x04ed124f GSEventRunModal + 192
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x04ed108c GSEventRun + 104
    20  UIKit                               0x01b6a8b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    21  ChatApp                             0x000e020d main + 141
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x0464bac9 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

```
- (id<JSQMessageData>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString * chat = [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Message"];
    NSString * imageurl = [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"media"];
    NSString * vidimage = [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"imgurl"];

    if (chat == nil)
    {
        if ([imageurl rangeOfString:@".jpg"].location == NSNotFound)
        {
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            filepathurl = [NSURL URLWithString:imageurl];
            NSString *filewithext = [[filepathurl path] lastPathComponent];

            NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, filewithext];
            NSLog(@"=====>%@",combined);
            NSLog(@"Video is Loading....");
            [image1 sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:vidimage]placeholderImage:nil];

            vitem = [[JSQPhotoMediaItem alloc] initWithImage:image1.image];

            // NSString * date12=[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];
            if(![self.senderId isEqualToString:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"UserId"]]){
                vitem .appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = NO;
            }

            NSString *dateString = [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YY HH:mm a"];
            dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
            dateFromString=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

            messageForRow = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"UserId"] senderDisplayName:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"]date:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"]   media:vitem] ;

            //   JSQPhotoMediaItem *vitem = [[JSQPhotoMediaItem alloc] initWithImage:thumbnailImage];
        }
        else
        {
            image1 =[[UIImageView alloc]init];

            [image1 sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]
                      placeholderImage:nil];

            JSQPhotoMediaItem *item = [[JSQPhotoMediaItem alloc] initWithImage:image1.image];

            if(![self.senderId isEqualToString:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"UserId"]]){
                item .appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = NO;
            }

            NSString *dateString = [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YY HH:mm a"];
            //dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
            dateFromString=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

            messageForRow = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"UserId"] senderDisplayName:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] date:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"] media:item] ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        messageForRow = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"UserId"] senderDisplayName:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] date:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"] text: [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Message"]] ;
    }

    return messageForRow;
}
```

Comment: Does `ChatpageViewController` use an array to provide data source items.  If so, that should be your prime suspect.

Comment: please provide datasource and methods of  `collectionView` you are using

Comment: I have added that method please check

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm getting the same error.